# How can I use Optional object properties on an Indexer properties in flowtype

Tags: generics, flowtype

My use-case is this: I want to create a type using generics to determine what a payload will be. What I want is something like this: (note: this code doesn't work)

```js
export type FakeType<T: {[key: string]: any}> = {
  [$Keys<T>]?: string // `?` is not allowed here
}
```

so, an alternative is to write it like this

```js
export type FakeType<T: {[key: string]: any}> = {
  [$Keys<T>]: string | typeof undefined
}
```

but then you get issues if you use optional object properties on the result anywhere else.

So, I feel like this must be possible. Looking for some help

Here is a contrived example of how this could be used:

```js
const SECTION = { ONE: 'one'}
type Example = {
  [typeof SECTION.ONE]?: 1
}
```

Works: https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAygUQMIBUCSB5AcjAvDAbxmwQC4YBycAUwoF8AoKATwAdqYEAPAQwFtWAGw74CDGDADaLdiABm8ZOmwA6EgF1yARgZ0gA

Errors: https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAygUQMIBUCSB5AcjAvDAbxmwQC4YBycAUwoF8AoKATwAdqYEAPAQwFtWAGw74CDGDADaLdiABm8ZOmwA6EgF0A-OQCMDOkA

References:

- [Optional object properties](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-optional-object-properties)
- [Indexer properties](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps)

Comment: Maybe you could step back a bit and explain some more about what you're trying to accomplish? It's hard to tell from this what you're trying to do.

Comment: @LyleUnderwood I added an example

Comment: It's still really difficult to tell what you're trying to do without more context, but I can tell you this: When using an indexer, you define two types, 1. the type of the keys, and 2. the type of the values. This means the type of _all_ possible values for the indexer. Also I can tell you that the `?` syntactic sugar on a property just changes the value to be a union with `void` (the same as `typeof undefined`). So `member?: number` is the same as `member: number | void`. I don't know if these things will help you, but they might be useful information.

Comment: @LyleUnderwood I actually ended up fixing this issue by rewriting it in a more complex way for the types.

That said, are you suggestion that `[$Keys<T>]: string | void` may have worked?

Thanks for the conversation.